# Include jss file from notes document as resource

Tags: xpages

The application I am working on needs to perform some SSJS on querySaveDocument of the document. The code it should execute needs to be maintainable without a Designer client (don't ask me why, but it's a customer prerequisite).

The .jss file is stored as file attachment in and I am trying to access it using as a resource of my XPage with a $file url. I tried both http: and notes: with replica id and db path, but the XPages engine can't seem to reference the file.

What would the format be of the "src" attribute if the resource?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post from Stephan
http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-86QKNM

I think this will help.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work with 'ibmmodres' path either. Resorted to client side javascript instead. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this will work. But you could load the library/code with your SSJS or Java method and just do a *eval()** or a value binding with the text loaded from your external resource. Then the SSJS code is available for the interpreter and can be executed in the event.

*: *eval()* is evil! You have been warned!

Comment: I am afraid that eval is the only way. Thanks for your response.